# I need to use INSTR in Athena AWS

Tags: amazon-athena

I need to use something similiar a INST on athena AWS I have the next code but Athena doesnt accept it

```
select substr(column_name, instr(column_name in '-')+ 1) as a,
substr(column_name, 1, instr(column_name in '-')- 1) as b from table_name;
```

Comment: Can you explain more on what functionality that you are trying to achieve using INSTR? string position ?

Answer (score 4):

The function you are looking for is called [`STRPOS`](https://prestosql.io/docs/0.172/functions/string.html#strpos) in Athena. The equivalent SQL in Athena would be:

```
SELECT
  substr(column_name, strpos(column_name, '-')) AS a,
  substr(column_name, 1, strpos(column_name, '-') - 1) AS b
FROM table_name
```

However, it looks like you're splitting `column_name` by '-', which you could also do with [`SPLIT_PART`](https://prestosql.io/docs/0.172/functions/string.html#split_part) in Athena:

```
SELECT
  split_part(column_name, '-', 1) AS a,
  split_part(column_name, '-', 2) AS b
FROM table_name
```

You can also split into an array with [`SPLIT`](https://prestosql.io/docs/0.172/functions/string.html#split).